# PostgreSql - Use result of query in next query

Tags: postgresql

I have this query, and it returns one row with one value being a number..

```
select sum(checkedcratesvalues.checkedcrates) from 
(SELECT checkedcrates
FROM  public.inspectionresultsstatistic e, crates c, powervisions pv, lines l, quality q where
c.id = e.crateid 
and l.id = e.lineid 
and pv.id = l.powervisionid
and q.id = e.qualityid 
and pv.name in ('PV111')   
group by checkedcrates, stopts) as checkedcratesvalues
```

Now I would need to make a new query on a different table, (in this case called `mytable` and use the value`checkedcratevalues` above to calculate a percentage like this:

```
select count, (count/checkedcratevalues*100) as percentage from mytable
```

how can I combine these two queries so i can use `checkedcratevalues` in my later query above?

Comment: 1. Please minimize your code to be reproduceable. 2. Please provide sample data and expected output. What do you mean with "second one". Please show what you want to do.

Comment: @S-Man the first query is  the one in the first box on top. the long one. That one is working and returns a simple row with one numeric value. Then i need to run a new query on a different table, (in teh sample above it is called "mytable") but on this query I need the value I got on the previous query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a CTE (Common Table Expression). You can name the intermediate value as column `v` in the `a` CTE, so you can reuse it in the main query.

For example:

```
with a as (
  select sum(checkedcratesvalues.checkedcrates) as v
  from (
    SELECT checkedcrates
    FROM public.inspectionresultsstatistic e, crates c, 
         powervisions pv, lines l,   quality q 
    where
      c.id = e.crateid 
      and l.id = e.lineid 
      and pv.id = l.powervisionid
      and q.id = e.qualityid 
      and pv.name in ('PV111')   
    group by checkedcrates, stopts
  ) as checkedcratesvalues
)
select count(*) as cnt, (100.0 * count(*) / a.v) as percentage
from mytable
cross join a
```

Also, please use modern join syntax, instead of those joins from the 80s.

Comment: Thank you very much. but I am not understanding where `mytable` went. the first query in the first of my boxes above is the query that returns a single row with a number. that number, needs to be used on a different query on a different table..

Comment: @sharkyenergy Revised the query to produce to use the value of the subquery into the main query.

Comment: thank you very much! this is what I needed.. :)